# Last (the newest) cross of simple moving averages in pine script

Tags: plot, pine-script, moving-average, candlestick-chart

Assume that we have sma(close,12) and sma(close,100) in pine script. I used cross()function to have the cross of these two moving averages. What I am interested in is to just mark the first cross (the closest cross to the current candle) in pine script.
I would appreciate it if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `if` operator or `barssince` function with the `bar_index` variable:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

// function for printing labels
print_info(string_info, bar) =>
    var l1 = label.new(na, na)
    label.set_xy(l1, bar, high)
    label.set_text(l1, string_info)
    
    
// cross 
cr = cross( sma(close, 12) , sma(close, 100))


// using if condition
if (cr)
    print_info("Last Cross", bar_index)


// // using barssince
// cond = barssince(cr)
// print_info("Last Cross", bar_index-cond)


plot(cr?1:0)
```

Comment: dear starr Lucky, it is very nice and useful code. first of all, thanks for it. However, it shows other crosses. I'd like to show just the last one without other crosses. is there any way to do this?

Comment: delete plot(cr?1:0), which is there just for reference.
plot any other data you want.